# Joint Probability density function given as follows $f(x,y)=30xy^2$ if $ x-1\leq y\leq 1-x , 0\leq x\leq 1$

Tags: probability

Joint Probability density function given as follows $f(x,y)=30xy^2$ if $x-1\leq y\leq 1-x$ , $\,\,0\leq x\leq 1$

Find $P(X>Y)$

I sketched the region of integration and i have found that the vertices are $(1/2,1/2),(0,0),(0,-1)$ and $(1,0)$ however i still cant find the correct answer after I did the double integration.
The answer given is $\frac{21}{32}$

Comment: Can you include the double integrals you have done  in the question?

Comment: You need to show your work when you post a question. Without you showing the double integral, how do we tell what mistake you made?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time asking question here, i dont really know how to type out integral, but the limit of the first part of the integral i had use are 0 to 1/2 for dx and -1 to 1-x for dy and the second part of the integral i had use are 1/2 to 1 for dx and 0 to 1-x for dy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have sketched the graph....you will need to integrate over this region to get $P(X<Y)$. Then you subsract it from $1$ to get the desired probability.

Here is the sketch(don't laugh at it...I'm poor at drawing).

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the integral is

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{x}^{1-x}30xy^{2}\,dy\,dx=\frac{11}{32}$$.

So $P(X>Y)=1-\frac{11}{32}=\frac{21}{32}$

Comment: can you explain a little bit further about why we use x to 1-x for dy?

Comment: Just look at the picture....what is the lower limit for $y$? . It is the purple line $x$. And the upper limit is the blue line $1-x$. Note that I am trying to calculate the complement of the event(because it is easier as it invloves only one double integral).

Comment: owh i see it now, thanks for your help